# Signed Char Decimal to Hexadecimal Conversion in C programming

Tags: c

I was trying to work on something and I basically have two questions. When creating a signed char, how do you
a) what is the convention of initialization and print statement used to print it in hexadecimal and
b) if I have a value of -32 assigned to my char, how do I print the hex without the 'ffffff' before the 'e0' and only print the 'e0'(without removing the - if it's possible)

I have tried all the regular syntax that is given, just wondering if it's something obvious that I am missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    signed char tempC = -32;
    printf("%x\n", tempC);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected result: e0

Actual result: ffffffe0

Comment: The `%x` format specifies that the corresponding argument is of type `unsigned`.  By passing a `signed char`, the behaviour of your code is therefore undefined.   To do what you expect, you need to convert the `signed char` to `unsigned char`, then convert that `unsigned char` to `unsigned` in order to print.   For example,  `printf("%x\n", (unsigned)((unsigned char)tempC))`.  And, no, you can't jsut convert it directly to `unsigned`, as conversion of `signed char` to `unsigned` will wrap based on the maximum value of an `unsigned`.

Comment: If you want to use `%x` in your `printf` format, then you need to pass it an `unsigned int`.  You can use `(unsigned) (tempC & 0xff)`.  In this context, `tempC` is promoted to `signed int`, then everything but the rightmost 8 bits is masked off, and the result is cast to `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Peter why do you say `unsigned` not `signed`? Both `-32` and `0xff` can be represented as `int` so according to [C11 Standard - 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2) the promotion is to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's how signed numbers are represented.

It's the 2's complement form.

If you take it as:

```
unsigned char tempC = -32;
```

it would result into `e0`.

The simple logic is that `%x` format specifier would print all `32` bits whereas `char` just has `8` bits. Remaining `24` bits are `1` because they were stored in `2's` complement form. As you would know `1111` represents `f` in hexadecimal. So `ffffff` would represent those remaining `24` bits

In case of `unsigned char`, they are not stored as `2's` complement, remaining `24` bits are `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments for the ellipsis portion of a variable-arguments function such as `printf()` undergo default argument promotions (C11 [§6.5.2.2 Function calls](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2), ¶6).  That means a `signed char` is converted to `signed int`.  You then attempt to print that as a hexadecimal value.  That strictly leads to undefined behaviour (the value being printed is not representable as both `int` and `unsigned int` and hexadecimal formatting assumes `unsigned int`), but you usually get what you see.

You could use `%hhx` to print the value as (unsigned) `char` if your system supports C99 format strings.  You could trim the value passed with `tempC & 0xFF`.

Comment: I suspect `"%hhx"` is still UB. Format expects an `unsigned` argument and `-32` as a promoted `int` fails the "not representable as both int and unsigned int".